# calculating payroll with php

Tags: php, algorithm, data-structures

I have a payroll database table that shows punch ins, and punch outs. Im trying to get the total amount of hours worked, but am having no luck.

The $time_array is a regular array, made from the data pictured below.

```
$time_array = ['8:55', '11:31', '12:34', '6:19' ];
```

Im trying

```
$i = 0;
$total_time = 0;

foreach($time_array as $time){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        $punch_in = strtotime($time);
    }else{
        $punch_out = strtotime($time);
        $total_time = $punch_in - $punch_out;

    }

$i++;

}
echo $total_time;
$total_time = 0;
$i = 0;
```

Ive attached a photo of the data im trying to use.

[image]

## Edit: Here is what worked

```
$time_array = ['8:55', '11:31', '12:34', '6:19' ];

$punch_in = [];
$punch_out = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($times as $time){
    //echo $name . ":". $time . "<br>";
    if($i%2==0){
        $punch_in[] = strtotime($time);
    }else{
        $punch_out[] = strtotime($time);
    }
    $i++;
}
$totally = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($punch_out); $i++){
    //echo "Time in: ".$punch_in[$i] . b;
    //echo "Time out: ".$punch_out[$i] . b;
    $result = abs($punch_in[$i]) - abs($punch_out[$i]);
    $totally += abs($result);

    echo "<br>";

}
```

==========================================

Is there a name to this algorithm strategy?

Comment: You need to give us more info. What does the `$time_array` look like? What's the database table structure? How are you retrieving the data from the database etc...

Comment: Can you please show your array value

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  - Updated with array

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$total_time += $punch_in - $punch_out;`

Comment: If @SoubhagyaKumar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547584/2524730) solved it for you, you should accept his answer as the correct one.

Comment: ok. i thought a upvote would make the green check appear, and im not allowed to upvote yet. Now  I see you the Topic Creator can click on the green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to set your timezone ,then from time array you need to get all punch time in one array and punch out time in other array.

then subtract from two array and get the add the results from substraction

here is the working example

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$times = array('4:30 am', '11:30 am', '12:34 pm', '6:19 pm');
$count = 0;
foreach ($times as $time) {
    if ($count % 2 == 0) {
        $punch_in[] = strtotime($time);
    } else {
        $punch_out[] = strtotime($time);
    }
    $count++;
}
$result = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($punch_out); $i++) {
    $minutes = ($punch_out[$i] - $punch_in[$i]) / 60;
    $result = $result + $minutes;
}
$res = intdiv($result, 60) . ':' . ($result % 60);
echo($result);
?>
```

### Edit: Here is what worked

```
$times = array('4:30 am', '11:30 am', '12:34 pm', '6:19 pm');

$punch_in = [];
$punch_out = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($times as $time){
    //echo $name . ":". $time . "<br>";
    if($i%2==0){
        $punch_in[] = strtotime($time);
    }else{
        $punch_out[] = strtotime($time);
    }
    $i++;
}
$totally = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($punch_out); $i++){
    //echo "Time in: ".$punch_in[$i] . b;
    //echo "Time out: ".$punch_out[$i] . b;
    $result = abs($punch_in[$i]) - abs($punch_out[$i]);
    $totally += abs($result);

    echo "<br>";

}
```

Is there a name to this algorithm strategy?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are continuously overwriting `$total_time`, instead of adding to it. It should probably be:

```
$total_time += $punch_out - $punch_in; // notice I also switched $punch_in and $punch_out
```

instead of:

```
$total_time = $punch_in - $punch_out;
```

But to be honest — and I don't intend to be mean here — you appear to be taking a rather naive approach to all this, especially if the sample data and the code snippet you have provided us, is an accurate representation.

I'll list a few issues that spring to mind:

1. Are you absolutely sure that punch-ins and punch-outs always come in pairs, they always alternate and that the first one is always a punch-in (see point 2. as well)?
2. Are you absolutely sure that times will never cross day boundaries?
3. Where have the `PM` and `AM` indicators in your data gone? Without those you will get unexpected (negative) results.
4. Have you tackled the [noon/midnight confusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight)?
5. What should the datatype of the calculation ultimately be? An integer, a floating point, a string, etc?
6. And what precision do you need? Seconds, minutes, something else perhaps?

Comment: All of the data has been parsed and configured down to these numbers. If midnight hits and there are no punches, its counted as a missing punch. Also, if there is a missing punch, it will not make it into the list.Lastly, and decimal form of total hours counted. Such as 5.4 or 5.02

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the 'AM' and 'PM' in your time array.

I also made a payroll system with time sheet.

I edited your code:

```
$time_array = array('08:55 AM','11:31 AM','12:34 PM','06:19 PM');
// $time_array = ['8:55', '11:31', '12:34', '6:19' ];
$i = 0;
$total_time = 0;

$time_total = array();

foreach($time_array as $time){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        $punch_in = strtotime($time);
    }else{
        $punch_out = strtotime($time);
        $time_diff = $punch_in - $punch_out;

        $total_time =  ($total_time + strtotime('00:00:00')) + $time_diff;
    }

    $i++;

}
echo date('H:i:s',$total_time);
$total_time = 0;
$i = 0;
```

Comment: this gives me 23 hours. Im looking for 8

Comment: what did you get?